# Connecting to react HOST from outside docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, networking, docker-compose, host

I am running a react application in development inside the docker file and this is the docker compose file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  my_frontend:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./deployment/Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 80:80
    extra_hosts:
      - "app.my-host.com:127.0.0.1"
    env_file:
      - ../src/environment/.env.local.dev
    volumes:
      - ../src:/app/src
      - /app/node_modules
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

The react application runs on the HOST app.my-host.com as host is provided in the environment file. This docker file builds and works properly and I can access the application from inside the docker shell using docker exec

```
curl http://app.my-host.com
```

will give correct result, but I can't access this from outside the docker container. I have tried different methods using extra_hosts but to no success,
`http:app.my-host.com` will give page not found on my windows laptop.
[EDIT: Adding dockerfile]

```
FROM node:18-alpine

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache bash git openssh curl

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app/

RUN npm install

COPY . /app/

EXPOSE 80

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Requirement: access `http://app.my-host.com` from windows laptop

Any leads will be greatly helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to expose the port you are using. For example ```expose 3000``` in your docker compose file.

Comment: Please edit your post and add your Dockerfile to it.

Comment: ```extra_hosts```creates a mapping between an ip address and a hostname inside a container acording to the doc: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#extra_hosts. You can access your app on http://localhost